# Load content from Div with Div Id

Tags: javascript

I have some code working but want to make an adaptation but can't get it to work. I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        var textBlocks = new Array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange');
        function changeText(elemid) {
            var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex; 
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind];
        }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

But only want to change 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange' into something to load the content from a specific DIV's with DIV ID's: content A, content B and content C.

Thanks, Eddy

Comment: not clear, you want to get rid of dropdown and have Banana as textnode inside "content B" div or access dropdown by its parent div ID ?

Comment: I want to keep the drop down, but instead of showing text Apple, Banana or Orange as text result of a selection with the drop down i want it to show the contents of existing DIV's. These each have their own DiV ID.

Comment: As my code is now it will after choosing from the drop down show under the drop down the text Apple, Banana or Orange and I want this to be text copied from Div's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood what you need try this:

```
var textDivsId = new Array('contentA', 'contentB', 'contentC');            
function changeText(elemid) {
    var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).value; 
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = document.getElementById(ind).innerHTML;
}
```

where contentA, contentB and contentC are ID's of DIVs you want to load. Here is some working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkwkn5mp/).
This is not an elegant solution, have you considered using `visibility=visible` property and CSS class swapping dynamically?

Comment: Thanks, Mike,  this works great for me!! This collects the text data from the hidden Divs ('contentA', 'contentB', 'contentC') well. For who doesn't know this is how I've hidden the divs and given them there div ID: <div style="display: none;" id="contentA">

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Keep going learning new stuff and move all style related things into CSS file, it's usually good habit until you really have a reason not to. Also please mark the answer and set case as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by

> into something to load the content from a specific DIV's with DIV ID's: content A, content B and content C

but if you mean you have 3 divs:

```
<div id='A'>Apple</div>
<div id='B'>Banana</div>
<div id='C'>Orange</div>
```

then you can create an array within javascript of their contents with:

```
var textBlocks = [document.getElementById('A').innerHTML, document.getElementById('B').innerHTML, document.getElementById('C').innerHTML];
```

however, this will only work if it runs in this order (i.e. your divs have to be inserted into your document before you run this javascript to build textBlocks. For this reason you might want to consider using jQuery to detect when your HTML elements are ready:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        var textBlocks = [];
        function changeText(elemid) {
            var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex; 
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind];
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            textBlocks = [document.getElementById('A').innerHTML, document.getElementById('B').innerHTML, document.getElementById('C').innerHTML];
            // ... do your other stuff here, like call changeText(..)
        });
    // ]]>
</script>
<div id='A'>Apple</div>
<div id='B'>Banana</div>
<div id='C'>Orange</div>
```